# Kindle Fire HD 8.9 not getting unbricked after going into fastboot mode

Tags: amazon-kindle

I have a Kindle Fire HD 8.9 inch tablet on which I tried to install stock android OS but failed somehow. Now the tablet when started shows only Kindle Fire logo.I have tried various links on XDA and found that it can go into fastboot mode but nothing more than that. Tried Kindle Fire Unbrick Utility which is failing saying " *device not found* " . Same goes with Kindle Fire System Restore tool for Kindle Fire 8.9.
So the problem is storage part of tablet not getting detected. Due to which it is not possible to send/ copy system restore images / original rom / any custom rom to the tablet.
Can anyone help ? 
Thanks in advance.
Following links I have referred :

1. https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011126
2. http://rootkindlefire.com/kindle-fire-root/how-to-root-convert-kindle-fire-hd-8-9-into-pure-android-tablet/

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, if you can't boot into recovery by first pressing the volume down button and holding it, while pressing and holding the power button, your tablet is lost. You will need recovery to flash the firmware that came with your tablet, if I am not mistaken. If there is another way, you might want to wait for another answer. If your tablet is still under warranty, send it back to Amazon for a one time courtesy replacement.